# Protractor: Stale Element reference with using conditions

Tags: protractor

I have a piece of code which is try to see if a text is not present in an element

```
browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.not(protractor.ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(self.btnDashboards(),dashboardName)));
```

where

```
self.btnDashboards = function() {
    return element(this.selectors.btnDashboards);
};
var dashboardName = 'foo';
```

However this occasionally returns

```
    Fatal error: 09:54:11.129 WARN - Exception thrown
org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=44.0.2403.155)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.15.322455 (ae8db840dac8d0c453355d3d922c91adfb61df8f),platform=Mac OS X 10.10.4 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 182 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
System info: host: 'Sujits-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '10.80.132.90', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.10.4', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, chrome={userDataDir=/var/folders/tc/89n0t1qs5p3fyw_n9hk1x7fc0000gn/T/.org.chromium.Chromium.QSwwCm}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=44.0.2403.155, platform=MAC, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: bbd4b5004df6ff3855bccacf8d16e8c0
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:268)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.getText(RemoteWebElement.java:152)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$EventFiringWebElement$1.invoke(EventFiringWebDriver.java:331)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.getText(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$EventFiringWebElement.getText(EventFiringWebDriver.java:381)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.KnownElements$1.invoke(KnownElements.java:63)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.getText(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.GetElementText.call(GetElementText.java:29)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.GetElementText.call(GetElementText.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:168)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is there a better way to code this so that it doesn't happen at all? Also Why is this happening occasionally rather than regularly?

Comment: How is `btnDashboards()` defined? Also, post the complete error traceback.

Comment: It seems as issue with the selectors itself. Also I can't say, that I like the code. It is possible to declare some variables, so Protractor doesn't process everything at once. Protractor allows inserting magic in the code, but the result is not pleasant.

Comment: @DejanToteff Could you explain the " It is possible to declare some variables, so Protractor doesn't process everything at once. Protractor allows inserting magic in the code, but the result is not pleasant" a bit more or link me to a doc. I'm new to protractor ( I came from a java background) so any tips would be nice.

Comment: Sure thing- Protractor is not as stable, as it seems.  Do everything possible to go away from complexity in your tests. For more - I wrote some tips on https://github.com/selfrefactor/Protractor-testing-patterns

Comment: Thanks. For my current issue i should assign each function call as a variable to improve this?

Answer (score 0):

Because browser.wait returns a promise you can use the .then({passed function}, {failed function}) to trap the error and try again.  Here's what I used.

```
browser.prototype.wait2 = function (waitFunction, timeout, timeoutMessage) {
  var self = this;
  return browser.wait(waitFunction, timeout, timeoutMessage).then(function(pass){return pass}, function(error){
    //retry if the error is a stale element, half the timeout
    if(error.name == "StaleElementReferenceError") {
      return self.wait2(waitFunction, timeout/2, timeoutMessage);
    } else {
      throw error;
    }
  });
};
```